# PHP file upload move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, file, upload

Php always shows an error when I try to upload the image to the server.
image: https://ibb.co/r4crqtF

The image size is 120kb and I think that is not a problem.

```php
$product_add_cate = $_POST["product_add_category"];
$target_path = "assets/products/".getImagePath($product_add_cate);
$target_file = $target_path.basename($product_add_imge);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["product_photo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "error";
}

function getImagePath($img_category) {
    $path = "";
    if ($img_category == "product_antidekubitni_program") {
        $path = "antidekubitni program/";
    } else if ($img_category == "product_bolnicki_kreveti_i_oprema") {
        $path = "bolnicki kreveti i oprema/";
    } else if ($img_category == "product_invalidska_kolica") {
        $path = "invalidska kolica/";
    } else if ($img_category == "product_stake_stapovi") {
        $path = "stake, stapovi i hodalice/";
    } else if ($img_category == "product_toaletni_program") {
        $path = "toaletni program/";
    } else if ($img_category == "product_ortoze_mideri") {
        $path = "ortoze mideri steznici/";
    }
    return $path;
}
```

Image HTML

```html
<input type="file" name="product_photo" id="fileToUpload" title="Izaberite fotografiju proizvoda" accept="image/*" required>
```

Comment: Check that the web server has permissions to write to the "assets/products/" directory

Comment: this is localhost

Comment: Also apache on localhost needs rights to write

Comment: are you using linux or windows?

Comment: this is on windows 10

Comment: Try using full path for $target_path, ex. "c:\\app_path\\public_path\"

Comment: Make sure your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute.

Comment: @AndreaManzi thanks for help! I use full path and it working now!

Comment: :-) you're welcome @Nina!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using full path for $target_path, ex. "c:\app_path\public_path\"

Answer (score 0):

Mb try not to use spaces in the path, 
for example, instead "ortoze mideri steznici" try "ortoze-mideri-steznici", etc.